# Template class specialization vs function overloading

Tags: c++, c++11

The title is not the best so let me explain: I'm experimenting with a custom mini-stl (for learning purposes) and currently implementing the `std::distance` function. The function must behave differently for random access iterators and simple input iterators.

**Function overloading**

Both std (in Microsoft's implementation) and EASTL use operator overloading to select the appropriate function, something like this:

```
namespace internal
{
    template <typename Iter>
    inline typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::DifferenceType DistanceImpl(Iter first, Iter last, InputIteratorTag)
    {
        // ...
    }

    template <typename Iter>
    inline typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::DifferenceType DistanceImpl(Iter first, Iter last, RandomAccessIteratorTag)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

template <typename Iter>
inline typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::DifferenceType Distance(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    // the last parameter of the function selects the proper DistanceImpl
    return internal::DistanceImpl<Iter>(first, last, (typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::IteratorCategory)());
}
```

I guess the temporary object (the category tag parameter which is an empty struct) will be optimized away since it's not used.

**Class specialization with static function**

What's about the specialization of a helper class with a static function?

```
namespace internal
{
    template <typename Cat>
    struct DistanceImpl;

    template <>
    struct DistanceImpl<InputIteratorTag>
    {
        template <typename Iter>
        inline static typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::DifferenceType Calc(Iter first, Iter last)
        {
            // ...
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct DistanceImpl<RandomAccessIteratorTag>
    {
        template <typename Iter>
        inline static typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::DifferenceType Calc(Iter first, Iter last)
        {
            // ...
        }
    };
}

template <typename Iter>
inline typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::DifferenceType Distance(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    return internal::DistanceImpl<typename IteratorTraits<Iter>::IteratorCategory>::Calc<Iter>(first, last);
}
```

**Questions**

- Difference(s) between the two solution? (Including performance and reliability)
- Advantages/Disadvantages?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the specialized approach, instead. That's what I'd use. The compiler is likely to optimize the dud temporary away, so you end up with the same results.

Comment: As the accepted answer says the specialized approach doesn't work with eg. `bidirectional_iterator_tag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag dispatch automatically handles inheritance hierarchies; explicit specializations don't. This is particularly important with iterators, because the standard iterator category tags form an inheritance hierarchy: `random_access_iterator_tag` derives from `bidirectional_iterator_tag` which derives from `forward_iterator_tag` which derives from `input_iterator_tag`.

The first version works out of the box when given a forward or bidirectional iterator by selecting the input iterator overload. The second doesn't and requires additional specializations or some other changes.

Comment: Oh, that's true, totally forgot the inheritance-problem. The object itself (the category tag) will be optimized away, right? So there is no performance penalty.